# is it possible to link an execution to a file in linux?

Tags: linux, journalctl

I was wondering if it is possible to create a link to an actual execution of an executable file on the file system?

For example i want to create a link to a command like *journalctl -feu myservice* as *log* and be able to issue the command *cat log* to actually see the output.

There is a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean `alias`

```
alias log='journalctl -feu myservice'
```

i don't know if I understood  correctly but that seems to be it.

you place this in your bashrc.

Comment: not exactly, what i want is to be able to perform cat (or other commands) on it

Comment: do you mean you want it to become a log file?

Comment: pretty much, so that i can change the parameters without changing the rest

Comment: just put that into a file with this sympole ">" pointing to the file. ` > file.log `

Comment: no, what i need is pretty much a named pipe but always linked to the output of the journalctl command